# Line break and text aren't working

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am new to LaTeX and I am having trouble with `\text` and line breaks.

My code is as such

```
$$\text{if} y^{(t)} \neq h(x; \theta, \theta_{0}) \text{then} \\ 
\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{k}+ y^{(t)}*x^{(t)}\\ 
\theta_{0} = \theta_{0}^{(k+1)}  + y^{(t)}$$
```

When I try to compile in TexWorks I get an error, then when I take out the `\text` parts it compiles but without the line breaks.

If any one could explain these two occurrences it would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: `$$` should not be used in latex, for single line equations use `\[` `\]` or multiline use `amsmath` package and one of its environments such as `align`

Answer (score 4):

You need `amsmath` package. `gather` is only an example of splitting. Choosing the proper one depends on the desired effect, in particular, the starred version omits equation numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

%$$
\begin{gather}
\text{if } y^{(t)} \neq h(x; \theta, \theta_{0}) \text{ then} \\ 
\theta^{(k+1)} = \theta^{k}+ y^{(t)}*x^{(t)}\\ 
\theta_{0} = \theta_{0}^{(k+1)}  + y^{(t)}
\end{gather}
%$$
\end{document}
```

[image]